# Like count for a fixed URL wrong when logged out

Tags: facebook, button, count, share, facebook-like

This is driving me mad, I have a facebook like button on my site http://www.myabandonware.com/, and the button have been showing 0 like for the site **when logged out of facebook**. When logged in, the share count is 5k.

When refreshing the page, I get sometimes 4.7k likes instead of 5k. I have checked the share count with the API.

I check the AJAX call with this URL : http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=172628266142459&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D9%23cb%3Df3662e52e4%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.myabandonware.com%252Ff188d369e%26domain%3Dwww.myabandonware.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myabandonware.com&layout=box_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&send=false&show_faces=false&width=55

Sounds like a bug to me, should I file a bug report on Facebook ?
This is maybe temporary, I've started the delete procedure of an old fan page that got 200 likes.

EDIT : this went back to normal behavior, I suppose this was due to the **old fan page** (automatically created around 2009 I think) **being really deleted** (after the 15 days allowed for rollback). The link count lost the ~200 fan of this page. I permanently deleted the fan page this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**: It is not a user-side issue.

You should definitely file a bug report. Although not new, the Like count integration for certain pages have been wonky as of late. Our startup recently encountered problems as well, so this is no surprise.